# RichFaces: Does navigation from one page to the next page using panelMenuItem needs to be enclosed in <h:form>

Tags: richfaces

Since i'm just navigating from one page to the next using richfaces panelMenuItem, do those panels/panelMenuGroup/panelMenuItem needs to be enclosed in the  in order for it to navigate successfully? I noticed that if i do not enclose those panels elements in the , nothing happens. But why do i need to enclose it in a form since i'm not submitting any data to the server. At this point, i'm just navigating from one menu page to the next. Please advice.

==========================================================================================

Portfion of the code:

```
<ui:composition>

<h:form> <-- if i removed this, nothing happens!!

        <rich:panel>
            <center><span id="clock">&nbsp;</span></center>
        </rich:panel>

        <rich:panel>
            <f:facet name="header"><center>MView Modules</center></f:facet>
            <rich:panelMenu id="MView"  topGroupExpandedRightIcon="triangleDown"
                                        topGroupCollapsedRightIcon="triangle"
                                        groupExpandedLeftIcon="triangleDown"
                                        groupCollapsedLeftIcon="triangle"
                                        itemLeftIcon="grid"
                                        expandSingle="false">
                <rich:panelMenuGroup label="Enquiry Management">

                    <rich:panelMenuItem>Profile
                    </rich:panelMenuItem>
                    <rich:panelMenuItem action="/sections/securityHoldings">Security Holdings
                    </rich:panelMenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!! You need to enclose it into  tag because you are navigating from one page to another. To navigate from one page to another you need to send request to the server and to send request to the server for page where you want to navigate you need a form :).